# Adding request specific data in Yesod

Tags: haskell, middleware, yesod, haskell-wai

I'm adding rabbitmq to my yesod application and based off [the documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html)(at the bottom) It looks like I'm supposed to open a new channel per thread which means a new channel per request in yesod. From what I can tell, my two options to add this are using [wai middleware](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-middleware-static-0.8.0/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-Static.html) or yesod middleware. In a WAI request I can use [Vault](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2015/10/using-wais-vault) to store arbitrary values like this. I'm wondering if `Vault` is the way to go or if I should be adding this at a higher level somewhere in a `YesodRequest`, and if so where?

Comment: So not every request needs a RabbitMQ connection (that'll cause way too many connections to RabbitMQ most likely). Typically you would have a pool of connections stored in your `App` datatype, and requests would withdraw a connection if they need it (and return it when they're done). This is the model followed by Persistent (`appConnPool` in the scaffolding). You can see this approach with Redis [in this blog post](http://maxgabriel.github.io/redis-yesod/). I don't have experience with Haskell's RabbitMQ package but I think you would want a setup like that.

Comment: If you're just developing something simple, it looks like you don't *have* to do this, since the amqp package docs say: "It is recommended to use a separate channel for each thread in your application that talks to the AMQP server (but you don't have to as channels are thread-safe)".

Comment: I haven't used it before, but it looks like both Persistent and Hedis use the [`resource-pool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool) package to create connection pools.

Comment: I won't create multiple *connections* only 1 connection is necessary but I would (maybe?) need multiple *channels*. I've read conflicting information about the thread safety of channels. It seems like for some operations they're thread safe and other operations they're not.